# SQL Server Connection and Vista 64 bit?

Tags: sql-server, windows-vista, timeout, 64-bit

I just upgraded to Vista 64bit. I was running the 32bit version without any issues. For some reason my connection to my SQL server times out. If I go to the server, everything seems to be ok there. I have unlimited conenctions to it and I can connect locally via the Management console. I have a web app running .net 3.5. Is I use the client SQL console it hangs, after a few minutes it is like it gets reset and then I can connect. Any thoughts? Hs anyone else had this issue?

Daniel

Comment: If you go into the Windows Event Logs for app & system, do you see any errors?  Have you uninstalled SQL Server and reinstalled the 64-bit version?

Comment: There are no errors, like I said in my answer, I think it had to do with my VPN. The SQL server is on a win 2003 32bit dev box. Thanks for the post though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I didn't have this issue on my 32bit machine, but when I am connected to a VPN I have the issues. Not sure if I have something set differently.